# Android: Twitter sdk: cannot import any twitter class

Tags: android, gradle, twitter

I'm want to implement Twitter login in my app, but I can't import any of the related classes.

In my gradle I added:

```
implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.3.0'
```

gradle sync works fine, app compiles and run, but I'm not able to import any of the `com.twitter` classes like `TwitterConfig`. If I write "Twitter" and let Android Studio suggest me the only option I get are `TwitterAuthCredential` and `TwitterAuthProvider` both from `com.google.firebase.auth`.

What is going on? Am I missing some gradle line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it importing only the dependecies I needed:

```
implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.3.0'
  implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-ui:3.3.0'
  implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:3.3.0'
  implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-mopub:3.3.0'
```

It migth be related to the large size of the library.

Comment: Could you take a look into this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68464892/twitter-login-crashed-in-android-version-11-unable-to-extract-the-trust-manager?noredirect=1#comment121001740_68464892. It will be helpful. Can I make this to work in android 11 itself?

Comment: @sejn sorry can't help you, we stripped out twitter login support as it wasn't that useful. as other said, the library is deprecated so it's not a good idea to use it.

Comment: Does the equivalent firebase will works as the same.

Comment: I think so, firebase still relies on you to get the login details from various providers (facebook, twitter etc...)