# Twitter login crashed in android version 11 Unable to extract the trust manager on Android10Platform, sslSocketFactory is class

Tags: android, authentication, twitter, twitter-oauth

Twitter login crashed in android version 11 Unable to extract the trust manager on Android10Platform, sslSocketFactory is class

Note: It works fine with the all devices except the Android version 11.

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.OAuthActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to extract the trust manager on Android10Platform, sslSocketFactory is class com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
```

Manifest File:

```
<activity android:name="com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.OAuthActivity" />
```

Sample Code:

```
 @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       loginButton = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.twitter_login_button);
       loginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
         @Override
         public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
             // Do something with result, which provides a TwitterSession for making API calls
         }

         @Override
         public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
            // Do something on failure
         }
        });
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        loginButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
```

Build.gradle

```
    implementation('com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:2.3.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:2.3.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
```

Comment: As far as I know the Twitter Android SDK you use is deprecated and is no longer supported (last release 2018). Use a different library or implement your own client to use Twitter API. https://blog.twitter.com/developer/en_us/topics/tools/2018/discontinuing-support-for-twitter-kit-sdk

Comment: @Robert Did you know anyother workarounds for this. I am using Twitter with Fabric.

Comment: Did you know equivalent twitter libraries to support the same in android

Comment: The error is because the code is calling the deprecated form of sslSocketFactory in the underlying OkHttp library. You could fork and modify Twitter Kit (it is no longer supported), or use something different. There’s no official Twitter SDK but various third party options are available.

Comment: So for sure, I can't able to fix the above error with the twitter-kit-sdk. @AndyPiper I think firebase Twitter login will suit this. Did you know of any other library?

Comment: There’s Tweedle (Kotlin), Twitter4J, twitter-client, JTwitter (Java), but I have not used any of these to implement login myself.